# What is the meaning of "usher" as in usher death?

Tags: meaning, expressions, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of "usher" as in usher death?

More than sex, more than faith, even more than its **usher** death, grief is unspoken, publicly ignored except for those moments at the funeral that are over too quickly.

Comment: “its usher death” refers to death ushering in grief

Comment: What definitions of "usher" did you find in a dictionary?

Comment: @Xanne - Not exactly.  "Usher", in the above quote, is a noun.

Comment: What is the context ? Author? Title? Sentences before?

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, of course it's a noun, but the point of the expression is that death is the usher to grief. i.e. ushers it in.

Comment: @KateBunting - As I said in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Definitions of **usher** from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/usher):

> Noun: one who escorts persons to their seats (as in a theater)
>
> Verb: to conduct to a place; to precede as an usher, forerunner, or
>   harbinger

In the above quote, "even more than its usher death" uses "usher" as a noun.  Essentially the usher is being identified as death, and this usher is who escorts grief to its metaphorical "seat".

Comment: Ah thanks!! I understand now!